# Paypal multiple items buy it now

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to add a deposit automatically to this paypal form as ideally a separate item on the bill. From other forums, support groups and whatever I have acertained that the below should be correct. It however is not, PayPal only detects item_name_1 based values and not item_name_2 based ones. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="foo@bar.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="<?php echo $item_name; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="<?php echo $thePriceToPay;  ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Deposit">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="<?php echo $depositToPay;  ?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo $currencyCodes; ?>">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="return" value="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/order-processing/">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="first_name" VALUE="<?php echo $nameExplode[0]; ?>"> 
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="last_name" VALUE="<?php echo $nameExplode[1].' '.$nameExplode[2].' '.$nameExplode[3]; ?>">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="address1" VALUE="<?php echo $yourAddress; ?>">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="city" VALUE="<?php echo $yourTown; ?>">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="state" VALUE="<?php echo $yourState; ?>">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="zip" VALUE="<?php echo $yourPostCode; ?>">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="email" VALUE="<?php echo $yourEmail; ?>">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are using a code for a buy now button, which only supports a single item.  You need to use a cart upload button, where you upload all of the items.

You need to remove the following line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
```

Then you need to add these two lines instead.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
```

Comment: Cheers PP_MTS_Chad - Perfect.